# What is the Relative Rarity of Blocks Generated in Minecraft?

Tags: maps, level-design, minecraft-modding

I was watching a tutorial from last year that was discussing how to create blocks that would be generated with the world.  I have lost the link to the video, but the basic issue I'm having here is simple.  In the video the presenter showed the **ChunkProviderGeneate.java** file in which there were multiple lines of code such as this for each of the available types of block (dirt, sand, various ores, etc):

```
for(int i=0; i < 30; i++){
        int randPosX = chunkX + random.nextInt(16);
        int randPosY = random.nextInt(128);
        int randPosZ = chunkZ = random.nextInt(16);
        (new WorldGenMinable(oreUranium.blockID, 16)).generate(world, random, randPosX, randPosY, randPosZ);
    }
```

Unfortunately, the code appears to be updated and I don't know where it is.  If it was I'd be able to answer a rather basic question.  **Exactly what is the approximate ratio of each block being generated in relation to each other?**  Or better yet, where can I find the code that determines this?

Comment: This isnt related to game development, better ask this question in gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RoyT. I think it's related to game development as I am looking for information about the specific code which determines the rarity of the blocks.

Comment: @BrotherJack Which has nothing to do with game development and everything to do with learning about a game.

Comment: if the OP is implementing this system then it is on-topic, but maybe the OP should disjoint the question from the game, and instead talk about procedural seeding of items based on depth.

Answer (score 2):

The [Minecraft Wiki article on Ore](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Ores) includes [a chart](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/File%3aPercentOfOreByHeight.png) of Ore density by Y-height. Looking at the noise in the graph I'd say the source is from empirical measurement rather than reverse engineering the code. This only covers ore; it doesn't cover relative density of gravel vs rock, etc.

If you want to look at the actual Minecraft code, you may find the [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/Main_Page) useful. It contains tools to decompile and deobfuscate the live Minecraft code. Their javadoc includes a [ChunkProviderGenerate](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/files/jd124/client/net/minecraft/src/ChunkProviderGenerate.html) class still, so you could start with the code they generate for that class. MCP also includes tools to help you build your mod in a way that's compatible with current Minecraft releases. I have no idea what the license issues are around decompiling Minecraft code in this way.

Comment: Interesting.  It would be better to have the code, but this still has some use.  Thanks.

Comment: actually noise is sometimes used in procedural seeding, and would make sense for "random" distribution.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to MCP, which could get you access to the code you are looking for.